# arangodb 3.1 behind apache 2.4 reverse proxy?

Tags: reverse-proxy, arangodb

I've been trying to set up apache reverse proxy to work with an arangodb 3.1.19

I know it's end of life, but...

I can make it work following :

> https://github.com/arangodb/docs/blob/00e2f46e2ff71aadb750fa1033c65fcd769bef61/2.8/cookbook/making-foxx-app-accessible.md

```
ProxyPass /arangodb/ http://127.0.0.1:8529/
ProxyPassReverse /arangodb/ http://127.0.0.1:8529/
ProxyPass /_db/ http://127.0.0.1:8529/_db/
ProxyPassReverse /_db/ http://127.0.0.1:8529/_db/
ProxyPass /_api/ http://127.0.0.1:8529/_api/
ProxyPassReverse /_api/ http://127.0.0.1:8529/_api/
```

I also found in the release note for new features in 3.x

> https://docs.arangodb.com/3.11/release-notes/version-3.0/whats-new-in-3-0/

reference for a way to 'mount' arangodb behind a reverse proxy,

This to me sounds very much like what I'm looking for, that is share the single instance of apache reverse proxy to reverse proxy for various services such as Kibana (/KB/*), ArangoDB (/ADB/*), ....

I can make things work for Kibana, but for ArangoDB, i'm not sure to understand what needs to be done.

here is what i do in http.conf :

```
<Location "/ADB/">
Header set 'X-Script-Name' /ADB
ProxyPreserveHost On
ProxyPath http://127.0.0.1:8529/
proxyPassReverse http://127.0.0.1:8529/
</Location>
```

in the mean time i tried to add the option to trust proxy from arangodb in its arangod.conf

```
[server]
frontend.proxy-request-check = true
frontend.trusted-proxy = proxy_hostname.my_domain
```

When i do all above, accessing the ArangoDB frontend directly works like charm, but when accessing URL :  proxy_hostname.my_domain:8443/ADB/_db/MyDB/_admin/aardvark/index.html it fails with a error panel saying :

> "The connection to the server has been lost. The server ay be under
> heavy load... try reconnect in X sec"

the browser inspector mod, show that the proxied request to URL   proxy_hostname.my_domain:8443/ADB/_db/MyDB/.... result in network requests like URL proxy_hostname.my_domain:8443/_db/POC/*api/collection?*=xxxxxxx

so it seems the mechanism to park the whole ArangoDB frontend behind '/ADB' basePath is not working.

I must be missing something, and I'd be grateful for anyones best suggestion to achieve this arangodb park behind generic reverse proxy frontend as a web app behind '/ADB' root URI.

cheers

Comment: It is unrecommend to expose the complete ArangoDB API directly https://docs.arangodb.com/devel/Manual/Foxx/Guides/Browser.html#exposing-arangodb-directly

Answer (score 0):

I use this script here to achieve the proxying to ArangoDB (allbeit its very basic) and isn't Apache but rather in NodeJS

I didn't need to mess with arangod.conf and it works with ArangoDB(E) 3.3.3 and I hope it will be of use to you.

```
var net = require('net');

var LOCAL_PORT  = 6512;
var REMOTE_PORT = <ARANGODB PORT HERE>;
var REMOTE_ADDR = <ARANGODB HOST HERE>;

var server = net.createServer(function (socket) {
    socket.on('data', function (msg) {
        console.log('  ** START **');
        console.log('<< From client to proxy ', msg.toString());
        var serviceSocket = new net.Socket();
        serviceSocket.connect(parseInt(REMOTE_PORT), REMOTE_ADDR, function () {
            console.log('>> From proxy to remote', msg.toString());
            serviceSocket.write(msg);
        });
        serviceSocket.on("data", function (data) {
            console.log('<< From remote to proxy', data.toString());
            socket.write(data);
            console.log('>> From proxy to client', data.toString());
        });
    });
});

server.listen(LOCAL_PORT);
console.log("TCP server accepting connection on port: " + LOCAL_PORT);
```